# Quarkus - how to start flyway migration with gradle

Tags: quarkus, flyway

I'm building a Auarkus application with Gradle. I don't want to do DB migration every time service is started, that's why I've set "quarkus.flyway.migrate-at-start=false".

Now, how can I start the db migration from gradle command?

I've tried by installing the flyway gradle plugin but that's doesn't work with Quarkus properties to read the DB credentials.